# Code::Blocks 16.01 File Tabs Disappearing (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

When I just start Code::Blocks and load a project, I can see the tab bar with files I opened from last time. But when I close all those tabs and then reopen the files, they don't show up in the tab bar. It is **not** because of that option to hide/show the tab bar.

[image: No tabs]

Also, once when I enabled file list, it didn't update its "space" and kept what was there before (project manager).

[image: Files list issue]

I've tried to join the Code::Blocks forum to ask this question on there, but I never got a verification email (yes, I have tried to resend it). That's why I'm asking this question here.

Edit:
Compiling from source gives the same issues (idk why it would have worked better, tried it just in case).

Edit 2:
Compiling Code::Blocks 13.12 from source gives the same issues as well.

Comment: Is it just a gui display glitch, e.g. if you minimise and then maximise C::B does the tab appear again? Or if you mouse over where the tabs should be?

Comment: No, it doesn't reappear ever. Also when I press around where the X button for a tab should be, it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the stable code blocks release did the trick.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Hope this helps!